Why are my giant carnivorous plants so aggressive towards escaped prey?
I have cave systems filled with gigantic carnivorous plants. They're basically venus flytraps with mouths filled with digestive liquid. They have controllable, sticky leaves and prehensile tendrils to help in predation. When prey is captured, the plants will do everything in their power to crush, suffocate, drown, and dissolve it.
Even if captured prey escaped by tearing their way out, the plants will continue trying to eat them. The plants will reach out with their tendrils and block escape routes with their leaves. Even if the plant had been greatly injured during its prey's escape and the prey fought back, the plants will aggressively attempt to pull its prey back to its maws regardless of any damage it sustains.
Predators are easily spooked by and are averse to prey that fight back because they risk fatal injury. Despite that, these plants will pursue even the most aggressive of prey when they could just wait for the next, hopefully meeker prey. Prey that are able to escape its trapping mechanisms should indicate that this prey could inflict damage that outweigh its worth in nutrients.
My question is: Why would the plants still be so aggressively predatory towards these kinds of prey?

Also, nature doesn't care about the survival of the individual; it cares about the Survival of the species
--- If a prey escapes and gets to breed, it could pass down traits that helped it escape. Preventing escape at all costs has nerfed the evolution of its prey species, allowing the plant species to thrive.

Escape is Already Catastrophic
Any escape after an initial capture is catastrophic; the plant has used precious resources like digestive acid and adhesive, and then the physical structure of the plant was damaged when the prey broke out of it.
Thus there are two possible outcomes:

The plant starves while attempting to repair itself
The plant re-captures its prey and digests it, gaining the energy and nutrients that it needs to repair itself

To make this plausible, you probably need to have the plant eat infrequently - which feels like it makes sense anyway. It's more like an alligator or a python that eats large, infrequent meals, and less like a mammal or bird that must eat basically every day.

You may compare it with a cheetah, which is using lots of energy to hunt and a series of hunting fails can mean the animals death. So ... it runs pretty fast and has 70% success, compared to 26% for lions. After hunting, cheetahs "rest beside the kill and pant heavily for 5 to 55 minutes"(see Wikipedia).

Internal Competition
Because your plants also aggressively compete against each other.  Not above-ground, but the root systems aggressively try to kill off other root systems via allelopathy (basically the root systems poison each other, it's normally inter-species but can also be intra-species, as in this example).  A plant that expends energy on making a kill and is successful gains nutrients needed to live, as well as the chemical building blocks for whatever poison (tannins, amino acids, whatever) the plant's root systems deploy to attack/defend against other plants.  Healing damage to the leaves/vines/whatever is minor compared to the necessity of securing more of the amino acids/whatever their typical prey species provides. The need is so great that if they "waste" energy in an unsuccessful hunt, not only have they given a rival plant the chance to secure the goods, but it's also critically weakened itself against non-damaged rivals.  Meanwhile a plant that takes even significant damage securing prey can quickly increase its allelopathic abilities to "hold off" rival plants until it can heal itself.

Pollination
The tendrils are flowered and every attempt to hold prey deposits more pollen on the animal. If the animal escapes, then more pollen leaves the cave and can reach other caves, if it doesn't, it's food.

This needs a bit of expanding on, but I think this is the right direction. The strongest prey will carry the plant (pollen, seeds, chutes, seedlings etc.) the farthest and are most likely to kill other animals onto which new plants can deposit and grow. The harder they fight, the more plant bits attach.

Animal language threatens trade secrets
A world with vengeful carnivorous plants might boast animals that have effective languages.  More than just having one call for a leopard and one for a snake - a language where they can say "Hey, those peaches that grow on a tree in the cave shoot out a whole bunch of spiny harpoons in your mouth if you try to eat them, then the trunk will try to drag you into the water.  Just chop off the trunk, wait a day, and come back and eat the peaches".  All in cute little grunts and trills like in a Star Wars movie, of course, but basically, some real language only they and the BeastMaster can understand.
These things grow in caves because it gives them great control over who sees what.  If there is more than one moving organism to be heard, they do nothing, even if it costs them some fruits.  Just us peach trees growing in a pitch black cave, nothing to see here!  But if there's just one, they brace for mortal combat.  Success means a huge store of food, enough for multiple plants to grow and reproduce -- but a failure that leaves an animal to escape could mean years, even decades of potential starvation based on that species' lifespan and penchant for storytelling.  Eventually, alternate species or combats between packs of animals could restore their status quo - but it is clearly worth it to them for the individual in contact with prey to put in every possible effort to preserve their secrets.

Natural selection:

plants which let their prey run away selected preys which would be more successful at escaping, ending up starving.
plants which aggressively pursued the fleeing preys left no teaching on how to escape them and managed to get more meals.


the harm is meaningless becasue the traps are single use.
The part of the plant involved is single or limited use anyways just like a venus fly trap. In a venus fly trap each trap only gets a limited number of triggers this sthing is the same. So actually destroying the parts has little impact the tissue is a loss either way, better to use it up on a lesser chance of recapture then letting it go completely to waste.
this is true of carnivourus plants in general. Plants are NOT predators for energy, they are looking for rare minerals or nutrients, like nitrogen or phosphorus. Things they can't get in the poor quality soil they live in. If the whole trap gets destroyed but they reclaim all the rare nutrients spent then it was successful. Energy spent on the trap is more or less meaningless as long as it get the essential nutrients that limit its growth.

Mindless
Only predators with some rudimentary thought processes can work out that this prey could do serious harm.  The plants can't.
Furthermore, the basic principles are its only way to eat.  The prevention of escape is just not curbed.
Logically it would be selected against once the nutrition won is less than that expended, but perhaps preventing prey from escaping keeps animals from recognizing so readily that the region is dangerous and so the benefit that way outweighs it.

Moving tendrils requires no more than reaction to stimulus.

Plants don't care much about wounds.
Unlike animals, plants don't mind much being pruned. Parts that were cut off will just grow back. Parts that were damaged can heal. So they can afford to take damage.
That said, in a cave, there is no photosynthesis, so the only source of energy will be food. Assuming water can be acquired from the soil, losing parts of the plant means the nutrient value of these parts is also lost, which is the real problem.
Our usual plants take energy from the sun and carbon from the air: limbs that are cut will decompose on the ground, releasing the carbon into the air as CO2, but the rest of the nutrients can be absorbed back by the plant's roots.
But your cave dwelling plants would care about carbon, so if bits fall on the floor, the plant will need to eat them to regain at least some part of the lost nutrient and energy value.
The plant would probably have specialized limbs: well protected ones designed to store energy and nutrients (like a thick trunk, a bulb, or potatoes), and for hunting, cheap easy to grow limbs.

Because food is rare
Something as yet undefined has caused these plant to evolve in cave systems. But the nature of cave systems is that they're really not teeming with life. Not like outside the cave system. The plants proliferate due to the need to reproduce as much as possible to perpetuate the species and the species has developed storage capacity so the food is efficiently consumed.
But there's not a lot of it, and it's sporadic. It's not like bunny rabbits go hopping deep into caves for the fun of it.
Consequently, when prey does show up, anything and everything is done to ensure that prey stays exactly where it belongs: bathing in digestive fluids.
Modifications to support the idea

Plants are inter-connected. Food that benefits one benefits all with diminishing returns over distance. Their root systems are shared, like the Aspen tree and they propagate by their roots like Tree of Heaven (ailanthus altissima). This will make them whomping hard to eradicate as you can't just kill one plant. You have to kill them all... and all their roots.

The threat against one plant is minimal compared to the whole. It's like threatening to destroy a single tree when the entire forest remains. Thus, the damage caused by prey in its attempt to escape is fundamentally irrelevant. Even if it resulted in the death of the plant that had it trapped, it hasn't threatened the "colony," which will act to keep the prey no matter what, knowing that the whole will benefit and continue.



Scarcity
Because in the real world food sources inside cave systems are strictly limited to and by how much organic material (and prey) enters the cave system from the external environment/world outside. Apart from fresh water cave marine species 'food' is limited inside a cave  to what crawls into, flies into or falls into a cave from the outside world. This creates a hyper competitive micro-environment where every single individual plant of the species concerned has to maximize (it's relatively rare) chances of catching a meal because that meal might be the only one it gets for months.

The carnivorous plants form a community, which communicates through its root systems, perhaps by symbiotic fungi. When one plant catches prey, all the surrounding plants benefit somewhat from the increase in available nutrients. Other plants "know", through the evolved communication system, when prey is present but has escaped from one of their fellows, and they extend their tendrils and wave their jaws around to capture the prey. Usually they don't do that because it uses energy, but it is worthwhile when there is prey present.

When they get wounded and the prey escape, it can lead to natural enemies of the fly traps tracking back the smell of the sap and eating the whole cave. So its a "either" we get it, or it gets all of us, by informing its friends situation.
They counter this by behaving similar to Japanese honey bees- crowd on any intruder and make absolute certain it does not escape. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBBChLRcvqA They even reward a "deeper in cave" catch, by sharing nutrients with the guardians who seal the door.

To supplement the other answers, I would like to leave a few suggestions based on one central point: evolution is a mess. It is not actually a global fitness optimizer for a given niche. It does not have a purpose. It does not always find the most optimal behavior. It can get stuck in a local minimum.
If it would take a long time for evolution to produce the most optimal traits, one will see a lot of suboptimal traits.
As some people have argued, evolution is the survival of "good enough."
So:

Maybe your plant species normally preys on animals where escape is an anomaly, and the prey can easily be recaptured. Animals that damage the plant and can escape the recapture attempts are quite rare. Sure, a plant that gives up after a certain point for certain types of prey may be incrementally better and have a slight survival advantage. But for the next million years, you're going to be seeing "good enough."

Maybe these behaviors are actually quite harmful, but are associated with a gene that codes for other very important traits, such as cell wall quality or whatever. Many genes in real life influence a wide range of characteristics. It would be better to evolve an alternate genome that allows for letting prey escape and having good cell walls, but for the next million years, you're going to be seeing "good enough."

Maybe the behavior is actually quite harmful, but there was a population bottleneck where the plants with more adaptive behaviors died. Eventually, the more adaptive behavior will arise again due to a mutation and rapidly  spread, but for the next million years, you're going to be seeing "good enough."


